# como cambiar el nombre unico generado por formidable

Tags: nodejs

no consigo cambiar el nombre unico generado por formidable de el archivo subido.
Quisiera cambiarlo, ya que cuando la borro, solo se borra de mi parte front y de mi base de datos pero no de la carpeta public/uploads(en la carpeta public/uploads se guarda asi ex(47fa38e9311d7d715544bb800.JPG). Me gustaria ponerle el nombre original y el id de la foto generada, en la carpeta public/uploads.para poder leerlas desde mi front end y poder eliminarlas  gracias   cuando borro la foto desde la parte front end la borra a partir del id de la foto

````
message
: 
"Request OK"
photos
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
category_id
: 
2
photo_id
: 
259
photo_url
: 
"/public/uploads/2016 Karl Marx.JPG"
upload_date
: 
"2024-03-12T05:59:44.000Z"
user_id
: 
140
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object ```                                                                                   
                                                                                       
```const createPhoto = async(req, res) => {
    const form = formidable({
        uploadDir: "./public/uploads",
        keepExtensions: true,
        customnewFilename: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalFilename); // Mantener el nombre original del archivo
        }

    });

    try {
        console.log("Data before processing:", req.body); // Log received data

        form.parse(req, async(err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Error parsing form:", err);
                return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
            }

            console.log("Parsed fields:", fields); // Log parsed fields
            console.log("Parsed files:", files); // Log parsed files

            //const name = fields.name ? fields.name[0] : undefined;
            //const timing = fields.timing ? fields.timing[0] : undefined;
            //const forPeople = fields.forPeople ? fields.forPeople[0] : undefined;
            const categoryName = fields.categoryName && fields.categoryName.length > 0 ? fields.categoryName[0] : undefined;

            console.log("Category Name:", categoryName); // Log category name

            const getCategoryIdByName = (categoryName) => {
                const categoryMapping = {
                    'toiles': 1,
                    'expositions': 2,
                    'enseignes': 3,
                };
                return categoryMapping[categoryName] || null;
            };

            const categoryId = categoryName ? getCategoryIdByName(categoryName) : undefined;

            console.log("Category ID:", categoryId); // Log category ID

            const originalFileName = files.file[0].originalFilename;

            const photoUrl = `/public/uploads/${originalFileName}`;

            const filepath = files.file[0].filepath;
            console.log(filepath)
            const user = {
                userId: 140,
                email: "aaa@gmail.com",
            };
            const userId = user.userId;

            const response = await PhotoDB.create(userId, photoUrl, categoryId);

            if (response.error) {
                if (response.error.code === 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR' && response.error.sqlMessage.includes('image_path')) {
                    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Error creating photo", error: "Unknown column 'photoPath' in 'field list'" });
                }
                else {
                    return res.status(400).json({ message: "Error creating photo", error: response.error });
                }
            }

            const photoData = response.result || {};
            const updatedPhoto = {
                ...photoData,
                imagePath: photoUrl || null,
                newFilename: originalFileName,
                categoryId: categoryId,
                filepath: filepath
            };

            return res.status(201).json({ message: "Photo created successfully", photo: updatedPhoto });
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error("Internal Server Error:", error);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
};
````